# Accelerate Python imports in docker image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have a complex Python application that uses multiple modules like pytorch, numpy. After profiling the application, it turned out that the import time is around 10 seconds! I run the application in a Docker container in the way that I start a new container instance, run the application, and kill the container.

Is there any way to accelerate the Python import in this context?

Can I somehow preload the Python interpreter, load the modules and freeze it in the Dockerfile, and when the application start in the freshly started container, the Python interpretater loads the imports much faster?

What is the effect of using py2exe or freeze in this context? Is it worth exploring, or it won't help to accelerate the start-up time?

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile? What distro are you running? Are you trying to install python on load? This is a great document https://pythonspeed.com/articles/importerror-docker/

Comment: Can you make a build stage that runs your script, makes the `sys.modules` dictionary and then pickles that, then when you run the script next, unpickle `sys.modules`? Not sure how much time that will save though

Comment: The docker file should cache the pickle stage and only re-run it if you change the requirements file

Comment: You can run the script while building your container - any *.pyc files which can be created while loading your program will be done then. That can speed up load times. Or make your application a long-running application which services requests.

Comment: @Tom McLean I like this idea as an experiment. Will give feedback when I have some results.

Comment: @Nick ODell We are on the same page in this regard: pre-compile Python files is already a gain, I want to have a second acceleration without having a long-running application.

Comment: @TiborTakács I would be interested to know if it does anything to speed up, was just a complete guess. Please let me know!